# Extracting full name and country code of geolocation with Twitter

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, text-mining

I am trying to extract full name and country code of a "place" from a json file that has thousands of tweets mined from Twitter API. I have tried to write the code several different times, but the code below makes the most sense to me. I was able to extract other data (hashtags, dates, followers with similar coding).

```
for i in range(len(data)):    

    if data[i]["place"] != "null":
        get_place_info  = data[i]["place"].get("full_name")
        print(get_place_info)

    else:
        print("No place defined")
```

This is the error I get:

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      3 
      4     if data[i]["place"] != "null":
----> 5         get_place_info  = data[i]["place"].get("full_name")
      6         print(get_place_info)
      7

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: have you tried changing your if statement to "if data[i]['place'] is not None:" ?

Comment: Thank you! That worked.

Comment: can mark my answer i posted as correct as to help others if and when needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*adding an answer from my previous comment...*

have you tried changing your if statement to

```
if data[i]['place'] is not None:
```